# Should terms & conditions upon registration be captured in the database?

Tags: database, user-registration

Should terms and conditions that user accept upon registration and making reservations on a system being captured in a database?

If yes, what is the proper way to do this (e.g. timestamp + IP + version number of T & C document)?

If no, what is the proper way to handle this in any other way?

Comment: Possibly a Q better suited to [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)? Interesting all the same. From experience larger sites, like google ask users to re-accept an updated TOS on a regular basis, so in that sense they would be recording the accepted version against user account. IP's should technically be logged elsewhere so it should be trivial to cross check this if necessary. GDPR is active in the EU now, so I'm not sure if this mandates requirements for this type of thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network. It is belonging to webmasters stack exchange. I have migrated the question manually myself and therefore closing this issue here. Please refer to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120367/should-terms-conditions-upon-registration-be-captured-in-the-database for any updates about this inquiry. Thanks!